# Combination of dielectrics in capacitor

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

[image]

For figure 2 in the above diagram, I derived the following equation:

$$\\E_{o}= E_{1} + E_{2}$$ Where $\\E_1$ and $\\E_2$ are the net electric fields or dielectric 1 and 2, respectively (i.e., $\\E_{1/2}= E - E_p$) 
And since the net electric field is positive in both cases, the above equation should be correct.

Taking $\\E_1 = \sigma/(\epsilon*k_1)$ and $\\E_2=\sigma/(\epsilon*k_2)$, I'm getting the final equation $$\\C_o*k_1 k_2/ (k_1+k_2)$$

But the answer key says it's $$\\C_o*k_1 k_2/ (k_1-k_2)$$ instead. I don't understand how this is happening. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Well,what's $E_p$ and $E_{1/2}$...?

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one. Particularly, if you consider the case where $k_1=k_2$, the formula of the answer key blows up; which should not happen.

Comment: @NehalSamee $\\E_p$ is the internal E of the dielectric due to polarization and $\\E_1/_2$ is $\\E_1$ or $\\E_2$, respectively

Comment: How do you transit from “E” to “$C_0$”...?

Comment: I hope you are correct                                       $V=E_1 d + E_2 d$.                                        $$V=\frac {E_0}{k_1} d+ \frac {E_0}{k_2}d$$ ... This leads to your answer ...

Comment: @NehalSamee it's a general derivation for capacitors.
 
$\\E = \sigma/\epsilon$, which gives $\\E= q/A\epsilon$ and $\\E=V/d$, which gives us $\\V=qd/A\epsilon$. Since $\\ q= CV, C=A\epsilon/d$

Comment: Know that ... I mentioned it later in the comment section ...Just wanted to know your way...

Comment: Hello, both the answers that you have given and your book have book given are wrong, in case $1$, net capacitance is $\frac{c_0(k_1 + k_2)}{2}$ and in second case, it is $\frac{2c_0k_1k_2}{k_1 + k_2}$.....in first case, law of parallel combination of capacitors is applied, in second, series!

Comment: Second case will be applicable only when the dielectrics cover equal width ...And  first case for equal heights...